# completely remove Jupyter

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I tried install jupyter, but somehow it cannot work with matplotlib for 3D graphs. I always encounter the following error:

---

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-dd74dfec8882> in <module>()
      9 
     10 fig = plt.figure()
---> 11 ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
     12 X, Y, Z = axes3d.get_test_data(0.05)
     13 ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, rstride=8, cstride=8, alpha=0.3)

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/figure.pyc in gca(self, **kwargs)
   1272 
   1273         # no axes found, so create one which spans the figure
-> 1274         return self.add_subplot(1, 1, 1, **kwargs)
   1275 
   1276     def sca(self, a):

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/figure.pyc in add_subplot(self, *args, **kwargs)
    962                     self._axstack.remove(ax)
    963 
--> 964             a = subplot_class_factory(projection_class)(self, *args, **kwargs)
    965 
    966         self._axstack.add(key, a)

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/axes/_subplots.pyc in __init__(self, fig, *args, **kwargs)
     76 
     77         # _axes_class is set in the subplot_class_factory
---> 78         self._axes_class.__init__(self, fig, self.figbox, **kwargs)
     79 
     80     def __reduce__(self):

/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/axes3d.pyc in __init__(self, fig, rect, *args, **kwargs)
     89         Axes.__init__(self, fig, rect,
     90                       frameon=True,
---> 91                       *args, **kwargs)
     92         # Disable drawing of axes by base class
     93         Axes.set_axis_off(self)

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.pyc in __init__(self, fig, rect, axisbg, frameon, sharex, sharey, label, xscale, yscale, **kwargs)
    435         self._hold = rcParams['axes.hold']
    436         self._connected = {}  # a dict from events to (id, func)
--> 437         self.cla()
    438         # funcs used to format x and y - fall back on major formatters
    439         self.fmt_xdata = None

/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/axes3d.pyc in cla(self)
   1043         self._zmargin = 0
   1044 
-> 1045         Axes.cla(self)
   1046 
   1047         self.grid(rcParams['axes3d.grid'])

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.pyc in cla(self)
    906         self.containers = []
    907 
--> 908         self.grid(self._gridOn, which=rcParams['axes.grid.which'])
    909         props = font_manager.FontProperties(size=rcParams['axes.titlesize'],
    910                                         weight=rcParams['axes.titleweight'])

/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/axes3d.pyc in grid(self, b, **kwargs)
   1254         if len(kwargs) :
   1255             b = True
-> 1256         self._draw_grid = maxes._string_to_bool(b)
   1257 
   1258     def ticklabel_format(self, **kwargs) :

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '_string_to_bool'
```

This did not happened before I installed Jupyter, so I thought removing Jupyter would help. I have run

```
pip uninstall jupyter
```

and also remove directories in `.ipython` and `.jupyter` in the home directory but whenever I run

```
ipython notebook
```

The Jupyter layout is still there, and I still get the same error... I have even tried uninstalling and installing `ipython` and `ipython-notebook` again but it is still not working.

Any suggestions? I don't really understand much about kernels...

Many thanks.

Comment: When posting errors, please always include the full traceback.

Comment: have you tried removing `.local` directory, i'm not quite sure the name of the directory.

Comment: It still does not work after I removed the `.local` directory...

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a problem with the apt packages of `matplotlib`. After I did `apt-get purge matplotlib` and `apt-get autoremove matplotlib`, followed by `pip install matplotlib`, it works.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Anaconda installation of Scipy, you can use `conda update matplotlib`.  This caused python, matplotlib, numpy and a few other packages to be updated for me. Matplotlib was then able to be imported and working correctly.  I didn't have to uninstall anything this way. Jupyter continued to work.

Answer (score 0):

After running
pip uninstall jupyter and
removing directories in .ipython and .jupyter in the home directory
run

```
jupyter --path
```

And then delete everything on the paths

> And be careful to remove the scripts in python installation directory
>   {Only remove the jupyter files}

And finally you will have no jupyter